# jquery sortable table update attributes with regex dos not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Why does the replace not work?
When I only use the COUNTER + 1 instead of the replace it works perfect.

I dont know why this does not work, but there must be a solution for it. I have to change this counter, because I want to save the table entries in a database with the same order and to do that i need the counter numbers in order.

```
<table id="SCHEDULE_1346334" class="table table_striped table_hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Zeit</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
            <th>
                <button type="button" id="SCHEDULE_1346334_ADD" class="button add">+</button>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form_group">
                    <input name="TIME_START_1" type="time" value="17:00" class="form_control"></input>
                    <div class="form_pend form_midpend">-</div>
                    <input name="TIME_STOP_1" type="time" value="21:00" class="form_control"></input>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="MONDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_MONDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_MONDAY_1" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="TUESDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_TUESDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_TUESDAY_1" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="WEDNESDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_WEDNESDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_WEDNESDAY_1" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="THURSDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_THURSDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_THURSDAY_1" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="FRIDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_FRIDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_FRIDAY_1" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="SATURDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_SATURDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_SATURDAY_1" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="SUNDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_SUNDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_SUNDAY_1" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="SCHEDULE_1346334_DEL" class="button del">-</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form_group">
                    <input name="TIME_START_2" type="time" value="06:00" class="form_control"></input>
                    <div class="form_pend form_midpend">-</div>
                    <input name="TIME_STOP_2" type="time" value="07:00" class="form_control"></input>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="MONDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_MONDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_MONDAY_2" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="TUESDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_TUESDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_TUESDAY_2" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="WEDNESDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_WEDNESDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_WEDNESDAY_2" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="THURSDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_THURSDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_THURSDAY_2" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="FRIDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_FRIDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_FRIDAY_2" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="SATURDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_SATURDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_SATURDAY_2" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="SUNDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_SUNDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
                <label for="1346334_SUNDAY_2" class="label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="SCHEDULE_1346334_DEL" class="button del">-</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $("tbody").sortable(
    {
        stop: function(event, ui)
        {
            $(this).find("tr").each(function(COUNTER)
            {
                $ID = $(this).find("td input").attr("id").replace("/_\d+$/", COUNTER + 1);
                $(this).find("td input").attr("id", $ID);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You define `$NAME` and then never use it. I'm not sure I understand. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry now it's a minimal example

Comment: I do not see any HTML or the jQuery Library Versions being used.

Comment: jquery is the latest version 3.4.1.. added now also the html table

Comment: When I run your code, I get `TypeError: $(...).find(...).attr(...) is undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes down to using `.attr("id")` on an element that has no `ID` attribute. In the first Column of your table, you have this content:

```
<td>
  <div class="form_group">
    <input name="TIME_START_1" type="time" value="17:00" class="form_control"></input>
    <div class="form_pend form_midpend">-</div>
    <input name="TIME_STOP_1" type="time" value="21:00" class="form_control"></input>
  </div>
</td>
```

As you can see, the INPUT elements here do not have an ID. This results in `undefined` when you call `.attr("id")`. As this is not a STRING, `.replace()` fails. To resolve this, you must exclude these elements from your selector or some other manner. Also, since the selector captures all INPUT elements, it is ambiguous and would not work as expected. So you should iterate over each and update their IDs when an ID is found.

```js
$(function() {
  $("tbody").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $("tr", this).each(function(COUNTER, ROW) {
        console.log(COUNTER, $(ROW).prop("nodeName"));
        $("input", ROW).each(function(I, INPUT) {
          if ($(INPUT).attr("id") != undefined) {
            console.log(I, $(INPUT).attr("id"));
            $(INPUT).attr("id", $(INPUT).attr("id").replace("/_\d+$/", COUNTER + 1));
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="SCHEDULE_1346334" class="table table_striped table_hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Zeit</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
      <th>Sunday</th>
      <th>
        <button type="button" id="SCHEDULE_1346334_ADD" class="button add">+</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="form_group">
          <input name="TIME_START_1" type="time" value="17:00" class="form_control"></input>
          <div class="form_pend form_midpend">-</div>
          <input name="TIME_STOP_1" type="time" value="21:00" class="form_control"></input>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="MONDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_MONDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_MONDAY_1" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="TUESDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_TUESDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_TUESDAY_1" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="WEDNESDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_WEDNESDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_WEDNESDAY_1" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="THURSDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_THURSDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_THURSDAY_1" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="FRIDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_FRIDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_FRIDAY_1" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="SATURDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_SATURDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_SATURDAY_1" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="SUNDAY_1" type="checkbox" id="1346334_SUNDAY_1" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_SUNDAY_1" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="SCHEDULE_1346334_DEL" class="button del">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="form_group">
          <input name="TIME_START_2" type="time" value="06:00" class="form_control"></input>
          <div class="form_pend form_midpend">-</div>
          <input name="TIME_STOP_2" type="time" value="07:00" class="form_control"></input>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="MONDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_MONDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_MONDAY_2" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="TUESDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_TUESDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_TUESDAY_2" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="WEDNESDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_WEDNESDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_WEDNESDAY_2" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="THURSDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_THURSDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_THURSDAY_2" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="FRIDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_FRIDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_FRIDAY_2" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="SATURDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_SATURDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_SATURDAY_2" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="SUNDAY_2" type="checkbox" id="1346334_SUNDAY_2" class="checkbox" checked></input>
        <label for="1346334_SUNDAY_2" class="label"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="SCHEDULE_1346334_DEL" class="button del">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, but I had to remove the quotations marks from the regex expression

Comment: What is the difference between these: $(this).find("tr") or $("tr", this) ?

Comment: How can i call this sortable function, because when I delete a row it does not update the ids...

Comment: @x0tester0x Please see: https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context "*Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so `$( "span", this )` is equivalent to `$( this ).find( "span" )`.*" So it's just short-hand.

Comment: @x0tester0x when you manually update the sortable items, you must then use `refresh` method. See more: https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work, the numbers stay the same... for example when I have three rows and I delete the second one, the last one has still the number 3...